# Merging collections in Meteor

Tags: meteor

Imagine you have multiple collections you want displayed on a single social news feed, for example `Posts` and `Users` (new signups). How would you reactively display both in a list sorted by creation date?

#### Idea 1 - merging in client

You publish the entities separately, and in the client, sort each of them by date, and merge them into a single sorted array, which you then display in an `{{#each}}` iterator. **Problem:** AFAIK this requires flattening the reactive cursors into static arrays, so now the page won't update. (Perhaps there's a way of making the page recalculate this array when any collection changes, salving this approach?)

#### Idea 2 - creating a new collection

You create a new collection, say `FeedItems`. When a new `Post` or `User` is created, you also create a new `FeedItem` and copy the relevant information into it. Displaying the items in the client is now very straightforward. **Problem:** Now there is no reactivity between the canonical objects and the `FeedItem` versions of them, so if someone changes their name, deletes a post, etc., this won't be reflected in the feed. (Perhaps there's a way of creating reactivity between collections to salvage this approach?)

#### Idea 3 - merging in the publication

Perhaps there's some way of sticking with the existing collections, but creating an additional `'newsFeed'` publication which would somehow merge them. I haven't seen any way of doing this, however. I see in the docs that you can publish an array of collections, but AFAIK this is equivalent to publishing the same collections one at a time.

Is one of these approaches on the right track? Or is there another I haven't thought of?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

By far the *easiest* solution is to merge them on the client in a template helper. For example:

```js
Template.dashboard.helpers({
  peopleAndPosts: function() {
    var people = People.find().fetch();
    var posts = Posts.find().fetch();
    var docs = people.concat(posts);
    return _.sortBy(docs, function(doc) {return doc.createdAt;});
  }
});
```

and the template (assuming people and posts have a `name`):

```html
<template name="dashboard">
  <ul>
    {{#each peopleAndPosts}}
    <li>{{name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

This **will** be reactive because the helper is a reactive context so any changes to `People` or `Posts` will cause the returned array to be recomputed. Be aware that because you are not returning a cursor, any changes to either collection will cause the entire set to render again. This won't be a big deal if the length of the returned array is relatively short.

Comment: Hi David, I have tried your solution to merge two collections but I am facing the issue, Could you Please look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37508474/meteor-merging-data-from-multiple-collections

and help me to sort out this issue

Answer (score 3):

Idea 1 seems to work out of the box. I created a new meteor project and change it as follows:

test.js:

```js
Users = new Meteor.Collection("users");
Posts = new Meteor.Collection("posts");

if (Meteor.isClient) {    
  Template.hello.array = function () {
      var a = Users.find().fetch()
          .concat(Posts.find().fetch());
      return _.sortBy(a, function(entry) { return entry.votes; });      
  };
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
      // code to run on server at startup
      Users.insert({name: "user1", votes: 1});
      Users.insert({name: "user2", votes: 4});
      Users.insert({name: "user3", votes: 8});
      Users.insert({name: "user4", votes: 16});

      Posts.insert({name: "post1", votes: 2});
      Posts.insert({name: "post2", votes: 4});
      Posts.insert({name: "post3", votes: 6});
      Posts.insert({name: "post4", votes: 8});

  });
}
```

test.html:

```html
<head>
  <title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
  {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  {{#each array}}
  <div>{{votes}} {{name}}</div>
  {{/each}}

</template>
```

This gives the expected list:

```
1 user1
2 post1
4 user2
4 post2
6 post3
8 user3
8 post4
16 user4
```

Then I did `Users.insert({name: "new", votes: 5}` in the console and got (reactively):

```
1 user1
2 post1
4 user2
4 post2
5 new
6 post3
8 user3
8 post4
16 user4
```

Comment: What if the collections have a document with conflicting (same) `_id`?

Comment: That doesn't matter. They are never stored in the same collection together.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this problem and I was wondering if a mixed solution would be better (or at least more efficient):

The solution proposed by David works great but, as he says, problems could arise when dealing with big collections.

What about keeping a local collection (just in the client), merge both collections into that local one when template is created and then register an observer (or maybe an observer for each remote collection) to keep the local collection up to date?