# Can I utilize an existing Meteor template to insert a new item?

Tags: templates, meteor

I have a Meteor app which creates a list of items. I have a Meteor template that represents an individual item.
Lets say that the logic in my app creates a list containing 4 items. I also have a button on the page that each time it is pressed should insert an item to the end of the existing list on the page.
What is the best way of doing this WITHOUT ADDING THE ITEM TO THE DATABASE FIRST (ideally I would like to re-use the existing Meteor item template)?

Answer (score 1):

You can still use Collections without sending anything to the database. If you create the collection with a null, that collection will only exist on the browser for the duration of your session.

```
Items = Meteor.Collection(null); // Somewhere in your client code
```

From the [docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mongo_collection)

> If you pass null as the name, then you're creating a local collection. It's not synchronized anywhere; it's just a local scratchpad that supports Mongo-style find, insert, update, and remove operations. (On both the client and the server, this scratchpad is implemented using Minimongo.)

edit

Here is a [good example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296712/merging-collections-in-meteor) of merging two collections. This is what that would look like with a local collection

dbtest.js

```
serverCollection = new Meteor.Collection('dbtest_names');

if (Meteor.isClient) {

  localCollection = new Meteor.Collection(null);

  Template.hello.helpers({
    names: function () {
      var namesFromDB = serverCollection.find().fetch();
      var localNames = localCollection.find().fetch();
      var allNames = namesFromDB.concat(localNames);
      return _.sortBy(allNames, function (curr) {
        return curr.name;
      });
    }
  });

  Template.hello.events({
    'click button': function () {
      localCollection.insert({ name: 'will' });
    }
  });
}

if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.startup(function () {
    // code to run on server at startup
    if (serverCollection.find().count() === 0) {
      // insert default entries
      serverCollection.insert({ name: 'peter' });
      serverCollection.insert({ name: 'scotty' });
      serverCollection.insert({ name: 'zelda' });
    }
  });
}
```

dbtest.html

```
<head>
  <title>dbtest</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Welcome to Meteor!</h1> {{> hello}}
</body>

<template name="hello">
  <button>Click Me</button>
  {{#each names}}
    <h3>{{name}}</h3>
    <br>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: How does Meteor know to order the list correctly if I have a series of items form the remote DB and one item in the local DB?

Comment: Just added an example that may answer your question. Meteor doesn't merge and sort lists but underscorejs does (which is why the package is included by default).

Comment: Thanks for this. One question, how do you then populate the remote collection, i.e. actually store the new list item in Mongo as well. Is it simply 1) a case of inserting to both local and remote collections, or 2) scratch the local collection idea, insert to remote collection and just turn reactivity off for a section of the page (where the list is located)?

Comment: You could take all the entries out of the local collection (new unsaved data) and insert them into the remote collection, at which point they will be "saved". Reactivity will then bring the new version of the remote data back to your view. Remember, you'll want to also want to clear the local collection otherwise you'll get double entries.

Answer (score 0):

You should have defined an helper for the items list that simply lists all the items in the database. Something like:

```
Template.Items.helpers({
    all_items: function () {
        return Items.find();
    }
})
```

For the button, you should define a click event that fires for the click and inserts the item into the Items Collection. As the all_items helper is a reactive source, it will automatically update and display the new added item in the template of the items.

```
Template.Items.events({
    'click #add_item': function (event,template) {
        //catch all the item arguments

        Items.insert(item)
     }
})
```

Comment: I have updated the question to state that I do not yet want to add the item to the database.

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish this task, you will need four things: an item list template, an individual item template, a template helper for getting the list of items from the database on your item list template, and an event handler for your add item button on your item list template.

```
<template name="itemList">
    <button id="addItem" type"button">Add Item</button>
    {{#each items}}
        {{> item}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="item">
    // Display anything pertinent to an item here
</template>
```

These are your two templates, the first being the item list template and the second being the individual item template.

```
Template.itemList.events({
    'click #addItem': function(event, template) {
        var item = {}; // Add attributes to the item object as necessary
        Items.insert(item);
    }
});

Template.itemList.helpers({
    items: function() {
        return Items.find({});
    }
});
```

These are your item list template event handler and template helper. The event handler inserts a new item into the `Items` collection when the `addItem` button is pressed and the template helper retrieves a list of all items for you to use in the item list template's `{{#each}}` declaration.

Comment: I have updated the question to state that I do not yet want to add the item to the database.

Comment: So, based on your question edit, you would like to basically do a 'soft' add to the items list that the template list shows without updating the database? Just so that I understand correctly, are you looking to do some sort of two-step process like this: click an add button to show the new item in the list, update some fields for that item, and then click a save button for this new item?

Comment: If you want to have a solution like this, it gets a little bit more complicated because you have to have that layer of a reactive data source that is used by the front-end for display, but is not yet tied to the database. I have been developing a large production app that does a similar thing and the solution I felt best was to use a [ReactiveDict](https://atmospherejs.com/meteor/reactive-dict) object that I attached to my parent template in the `created` template function and tied all of my front-end components to that reactive data source instead of the database directly.

Comment: Then, upon clicking the save button, I would save the contents of the `ReactiveDict` object to the database. The `ReactiveDict` gets you the 'soft' add while the save button gets you the actual add.

Comment: I might need some help on this. Wanna get in touch via email?