# Meteor - Merging Data from multiple Collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, merge, mongodb-query

I have been doing lots of search on how to merge data from multiple collections and then send it to the Template using the Template Helper Function client side.

I referred to the solution given at : [Merging collections in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296712/merging-collections-in-meteor)

Below is my Code:

**Template HTML :**

```
  <template name="search_results">

    <div class="col-md-12">

        {{#if Template.subscriptionsReady}}


        <table id="datatable" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Type</th>
         <th>Project Name</th>
         <th>_id</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>

                {{#each SearchData}}
                <tr>
                <td>{{search_type}}</td>
                <td>{{name}}</td>
                <th>{{_id}}</th>
                </tr>
                {{/each}}

                </tbody>
            </table>

        {{else}}
        <div class="loading">{{>spinner}}</div>
        {{/if}}


    </div>


</template>
```

**Template Helper Function:**

```
Template.search_results.helpers({

    SearchData: function() {

        var project_name = Router.current().params.query.search;

        var Projects = Projects.find({project_name: { $regex : project_name, $options:"i" } }).map( function ( Project ) { return { _id: Project._id, name: Project.project_name, search_type: 'Projects' }; }).fetch();

        var CustomerAccounts =  CustomerAccounts.find({account_name: { $regex : project_name, $options:"i" } }).map( function ( CustomerAccount ) { return { _id: CustomerAccount._id, name: CustomerAccount.account_name, search_type: 'Accounts' }; }).fetch();

        var docs = Projects.concat(CustomerAccounts);

        return docs;

    }


  });
```

I have tried the following code to send data from the single collection and its working fine:

```
return Projects.find({project_name: { $regex : project_name, $options:"i" } }).map( function ( Project ) { return { _id: Project._id, name: Project.project_name, search_type: 'Projects' }; });
```

But I want to merge two collections and send the data to Template, Where I am wrong and what is the good way to do it?

Comment: This question needs the following: (1) sample input, (2) desired output, (3) current output including any errors in the console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cursor's [map](http://docs.meteor.com/api/collections.html#Mongo-Cursor-map) function returns an array, so calling `fetch` on that array would throw an error. Try removing the `fetch` calls and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was doing one Typo Mistake Now the Issue is corrected:

**Check My Rectified Code Below**

```
    var projects = Projects.find({project_name: { $regex : project_name, $options:"i" } }).map( function ( Project ) { return { _id: Project._id, name: Project.project_name, search_type: 'Projects' }; });

    var customeraccounts =  CustomerAccounts.find({account_name: { $regex : project_name, $options:"i" } }).map( function ( CustomerAccount ) { return { _id: CustomerAccount._id, name: CustomerAccount.account_name, search_type: 'Accounts' }; });

    var docs = projects.concat(customeraccounts);

    return docs;
```

I have created variable name same as Collection Name, then reailsed and then changed it to lowercase, instead of ***var Projects*** I changed it to ***var projects***,

Second thing I have also removed fetch()

The issue is Solved now , As David Suggested me to remove fetch() , I am marking his Answer as Correct although my code has another issue of variable name.