# Combining Meteor Collections

Tags: javascript, meteor, infinite-scroll

This problem is in relation to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299272/to-achieve-infinite-scroll-in-meteorjs-showing-latest-data-first).

In short, I'm trying to build a newsfeed, much like Facebook's with infinite scroll functionality. In this newsfeed, I would like to display posts from different collections, according to date posted. I've got a partially working code (check below), **but the problem is**, because I've set the `limit` to 3, upon refresh, the site will serve 3 posts from each collections, and not 3 latest posts from any collections.

I think it's because of either the way I publish the collections, or the way I subscribe them. Here are the codes:

**publish.js**

```
Meteor.publish('newsfeed', function(limit){
  data = [
    Status.find({}, {limit:limit, sort: {createdAt:-1}}),
    Story.find({}, {limit:limit, sort: {createdAt:-1}}),
    Lesson.find({}, {limit:limit, sort: {createdAt:-1}}),
    Images.find(),
    Documents.find()
  ];
  return data;
});
```

**statusBox.js**

```
newsfeed_increment = 3;
Session.setDefault('newsfeedLimit', newsfeed_increment);
Deps.autorun(function(){
  Meteor.subscribe('newsfeed', Session.get('newsfeedLimit'));
});

Template.statusBox.helpers({
  //Merging few collections into one template helper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21296712/merging-collections-in-meteor
  newsfeedList: function(){
    var hza = Status.find().fetch()
      .concat(Story.find().fetch())
      .concat(Lesson.find().fetch());
      var sortie = _.sortBy(hza, function(doc) { return doc.createdAt; });
      var ietros = sortie.reverse();
      return ietros;
...
});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should sort and do other filters on the client-side as well, i.e, in

**statusBox.js**

```
Template.statusBox.helpers({
  newsfeedList: function(){
    var limit = Session.get('newsfeedLimit');
    var hza = Status.find({limit:limit, sort: {createdAt:-1}).fetch()
      .concat(Story.find({limit:limit, sort: {createdAt:-1}).fetch())
      .concat(Lesson.find({limit:limit, sort: {createdAt:-1}).fetch());
    var sortie = _.sortBy(hza, function(doc) { return doc.createdAt; });
    var ietros = sortie.reverse();
   return ietros;
   ...
});
```